# Django: In deployment where stays the static files of admin?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-staticfiles

i have a web application runing, the statics files from apps works but in /admin/ seems like doesn't have a css file. In the production the admin page works fine.

My question is where is the css file from admin page of django?

Just in case if somebody want to check, this is my configuration of static files of the web-app in deployment

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/apps_wsgi/generic_name/main/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/apps_wsgi/generic_name/main/media/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `collectstatic` management command. There are static files for other apps in the `site-packages` of your virtualenv and that command will copy/generate them into the correct static files location for your application.